# Building network topology to download file from multiple servers

Tags: networking, network-programming, topology, ns-3

In my Network Programming class, I got a topic like this:

---

Let’s say there are network topology with configuration like below:

[image]

The S1, S2, S3 contains the same file DATA.dat.

---

Design the protocol and code a server program that install on servers S1, S2, S3 and a client program install on client C to **download the file Data.dat from servers S1, S2, S3 in the same time**, and the downloaded **file is not corrupted**.

Network configuration:

- Bandwidth between servers and router is not known (in range 100kbps ~ 1000kbps)
- Bandwidth between client C and router is 10Mbps.
- Packet loss rate is not known.

---

I have no idea about the way to solve this. So I hope you could give me some keywords to solve this. Thanks a lot

Comment: You should read about peer-to-peer protocols.

Answer (score 0):

Your protocol should first find meta-information about the download. This information must contain a list of servers, filelength, and a hash (md5, rc4 or similar to verify that the file is not corrupt when finished).

The protocol must have the possibility to download the file by chunks. This way you can connect to multiple servers as once and download different chunks in parallel. A typical chunk size could be 1MB (and the last chunk will be smaller).